# Send a matrix as a proc argument in Chapel

Tags: chapel

I'm getting an error when I try to send a matrix into a proc.  I'm pretty sure I'm doing something very wrong, can't figure it out.

```
use LinearAlgebra;    
proc main() {
  var A = Matrix(
       [0.0, 0.8, 1.1, 0.0, 2.0]
      ,[0.8, 0.0, 1.3, 1.0, 0.0]
      ,[1.1, 1.3, 0.0, 0.5, 1.7]
      ,[0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.5]
      ,[2.0, 0.0, 1.7, 1.5, 0.0]
      );

  check_dims(A);
}

proc check_dims(A: Matrix) { 
  var t: bool  = false;
  if (A.domain.dim(1) == A.domain.dim(2)){
    t = true;
  }
  return t;
}
```

Gives me

```
mad.chpl:3: In function 'main':
mad.chpl:14: error: unresolved call 'check_dims([domain(2,int(64),false)] real(64))'
mad.chpl:17: note: candidates are: check_dims(A: Matrix)
```

I'm using `chpl Version 1.15.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear algebra objects (like matrices and vectors) are [represented as arrays](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/1.15/modules/packages/LinearAlgebra.html#linear-algebra-api) in Chapel. Therefore, changing `Matrix` (a type that does not exist) to `[]` (the syntax for array-type) should work as expected:

```
use LinearAlgebra;    
proc main() {
  var A = Matrix(
       [0.0, 0.8, 1.1, 0.0, 2.0]
      ,[0.8, 0.0, 1.3, 1.0, 0.0]
      ,[1.1, 1.3, 0.0, 0.5, 1.7]
      ,[0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.5]
      ,[2.0, 0.0, 1.7, 1.5, 0.0]
      );

  check_dims(A);
}

proc check_dims(A: []) { 
  var t: bool  = false;
  // method is dim()
  if (A.domain.dim(1) == A.domain.dim(2)){
    t = true;
  }
  return t;
}
```

Comment: Side note: [`isSquare()`](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/1.15/modules/packages/LinearAlgebra.html#LinearAlgebra.isSquare) might accomplish what you're attempting to do with `check_dims()`

Comment: you go home, bencray

Comment: @bencray: Is it clear to you why the compiler is even accepting `Matrix` as a formal type?  Is there a type or type alias with the name `Matrix`?  Is this a case of the compiler being over-permissive (e.g., allowing non-type function names to be used as type identifiers?)

Comment: @Brad -- really great question. There is not a type with the name `Matrix`. I believe the compiler is checking if `Matrix` is defined as *something* at scope resolve, and then moving on. To improve on this, the compiler could go further and check if `Matrix` is a `type` or `type function` within scope resolve. I will open an issue on this for further discussion.